# Backing up my wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, backup, database-backups

Hi I have a lot of wordpress sites (more than 30) and I'm currently using MainWP plugin, but it is taking too much resources and sometimes it takes my server down.

Does anyone knows if there is a plugin that backups several sites in one wp admin console like mainWP?, I know that there are several options but they dont have the option to control every site in just a single WP panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been using **UpdraftPlus** for a long time and they are great. They allow you to ***backup to Google Drive or Dropbox or download directly***. It is a 360 degree backup solution and you can ***backup multiple websites*** from a central location by using a WordPress Multi-Site setup. They also have a free plan.

https://updraftplus.com/
https://updraftplus.com/updraftplus-full-feature-list/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/

Also, I have heard many good things about **BackupBuddy by iThemes**, although they cost much more. Depending on your budget it may also be useful to look into this more:

https://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

Answer (score 1):

MainWP, ManageWP, InfiniteWP, BackupBuddy and similar services use the same approach: a PHP script relying on site server resources to create a backup onsite and upload it offsite.

That's why for ManageWP Orion we're using a new approach: a large portion of the backup process is being done offsite, reducing the site server load to a fraction of what you're experiencing now.

The new backup system will be introduced into the ManageWP Orion beta in 1-2 weeks, I recommend checking it out.

Comment: Reading this 5 years later. ManageWP is amazing, and I use it for a lot more than just the backups now. Great insight.